# bash grep array and output array separately

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to grep from a given array in a file. I need the count of the array unit and I'm hoping to get the output count per unit, eg: `U10 => 2` etc. but when I add more than one unit into the array it seems grep sums up and outputs a single combined count.

Here is my code so far, any help or direction on where to search or where to start would be helpful.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 echo "Enter file to check:"
 read file
 args=("U10" "U12" "U14")
 pat=$(echo ${args[@]}|tr " " "|")
 grep detected /public/files/$file | grep -Ec "$pat"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying a regex (`U10|U12|U14`) to `grep` and seeking for the count.  This is why you're observing that you're getting the sum of the count of individual matches.

Specify one pattern at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter file to check:"
read file
args=("U10" "U12" "U14")
for pat in ${args[@]}; do
  echo -ne "${pat}\t" ; grep detected /public/files/$file | grep -c "$pat"
done
```

You probably don't need to pass `-E` to `grep`.

Comment: Thanks devnull, it works as I wanted it to work! Thanks Again!